# How can I protect a hose and wire in a high-traffic area?

Tags: plumbing, wiring, outdoor

It's about 20' from my RV to the water supply and electric receptacle. This is a high-traffic area, and having foot (and car!) traffic on the hose and wire seem like a bad idea.

Ideally, I'd run them underground, but that will have to come later. What can I do today?

One idea is to cut a piece of 4" pipe in half, to use as a cover. What else?

Comment: How permanent does this need to be? Are you living out of your RV for the long haul? Is this just living in the RV during construction?

Answer (score 7):

In the military, we used to make cable protectors out of 2X4's and scrapes of plywood. Simply lay the 2X4's down a few inches apart and attach small squares of plywood every few feet to keep the 2X4's spaced and parallel. run the hose and wires between the 2X4's. You could also run the narrow strip of plywood or a board the full length of the 2X4's and recess the whole thing 1 1/2 inches into the ground so it is flush, not sticking up above the ground grade. Cheap and easy.

Answer (score 6):

The only thing I would add too [shirlock homes answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7724/how-can-i-protect-a-hose-and-wire-in-a-high-traffic-area/7729#7729) is:

- The 2x4's will create a trip hazard (unless I am misunderstanding the [given answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7724/how-can-i-protect-a-hose-and-wire-in-a-high-traffic-area/7729#7729)), and seeing as you say *"This is a high-traffic area..."*, I would be inclined to slightly modify the [given answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7724/how-can-i-protect-a-hose-and-wire-in-a-high-traffic-area/7729#7729) and introduce "gentle" ramps/slopes to either side of the 2x4 - Plywood construction.

Or if you want to spend a little bit more up front, by save a little bit of construction time, have a look at something like:

- [Off the shelf, cable protectors, cord covers/protectors & cable ramps](http://www.electriduct.com/Cable-Protectors.html)

Please note I have no affiliation with the above link, just giving it as an example (1st thing that turned up on a google search).

Comment: I get catalogs from ULine that have similar things. HarborFreight may have them locally for cheap. McMaster-Carr has everything. TSC may even have these.

Comment: Jay could also recess the wood protector slightly into the soil to make access smoother.